# Path of steepest descent

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I'm given an elevation on a hill by $f(x,y)= 200 - y^2 -4x^2$. Now I have to show that from the point (1,2) the path of steepest descent is $y=2x^{1/4}$ as it travels down the hill.

I attempted it by finding the partial derivatives of x and y.

So I have $df/dx = -8x$ and $df/dy = -2y$.

I also know that the path of steepest descent is in the opposite direction of the gradient, so the signs would be switched.

I have no idea how to prove this from here though.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

$$ Gradient f = <-8x,-2y>$$

$$ \frac {dx}{dt} = 8x$$
$$ \frac {dy}{dt} = 2y$$

$$ \frac {dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\frac {dy}{dt}}{\frac {dx}{dt}}$$

$$\frac {dy}{2y} = \frac {dx}{8x}$$
$$\frac {dy}{y} = \frac {dx}{4x}$$
Integrating, we get

$$ ln(y) = \frac {1}{4}ln(x) + C$$

Evaluate at (1,2) => ln2 = C

Substituting back

we get the path of steepest descent
$$ln(y) = \frac {1}{4}ln(x) + ln(2)$$

$$ln(y) = ln(2.x^{\frac{1}{4}})$$

$$ y = 2.x^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that any directional partial derivative can be expressed as:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial l}=f_x\cos \alpha +f_y\sin \alpha
$$
where $\alpha$ is the directional angle of $l$.

Based on this, we apply Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality:

$$
|\langle x,y\rangle|\le ||x||\ ||y||
$$
Plug [$f_x$, $f_y$] and [$\cos \alpha$, $\sin\alpha$] into x and y, respectively.

the = sign holds iff x and y are linearly dependent. More specifically, if x=ky,where k>=0,

$$
\langle x,y\rangle=||x||\ ||y||=||x||
$$

if k<0;
then

$$
\langle x,y\rangle=- ||x||\ ||y||=-||x||
$$
note that  $||y||=\sqrt{\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha}=1$.

the first case is the gradient case(steepest increasing), the latter is the opposite gradient case(steepest decreasing).